# Android application xpath with content desc - handle the line break

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, automation, appium

Objective: To click on Access for all guest users.
I am unable to find this element.

uiautomatorviewer shows the following screenshot.
[image]

Content description is following copy/pasted
"Access for all guest users
Provider not listed? Stay tuned, we will be adding more TV providers shortly."

Notice: the line break after user. I believe this is why my xpath is not working.

My xpath is:
"//android.view.View[@content-desc ='Access for all guest usersProvider not listed? Stay tuned, we will be adding more TV providers shortly.']"

I cannot use index instead of content-desc because of the object in layers above have the same class and index.

Using tap to a specific might solve the problem but is not a good solution.
any ideas on how to handle that linebreak.

Comment: can you try using contains like `//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Access for all guest users')]`

Comment: I have tried it already. Does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice the XML hierarchy, you will notice that your element is inside a WebView (3rd node from top). So its not getting identified. You have to first switch to WebView and then use your code.

The way you mentioned the xpath should work, once you switch to WebView.

Comment: Thank you Anish, 
When you say switch to WebView, how do I switch to that specific webview? 
It is a not frame. 
driver.getContextHandles();

>>???

Comment: `Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
 if(contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
  driver.context("WEBVIEW");
  break;
 }
}`

Comment: The contextNames in above case give out something like [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_<APP_PKG_NAME>]. So you can switch to the one which has WEBVIEW in it